# Why does TypeScript allow assignment of a subtype to an object property?

Tags: typescript

Consider this example:

```
type Base = {
    a: number,
    b: number
}

type SubTest = Base & {
    c: number
}

function run(arg: { prop: Base }) {
    arg.prop = {
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    };
}

const prop: SubTest = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
};

const originalObject = { prop };

run(originalObject);

console.log(originalObject.prop.c.toFixed(2));
```

TypeScript seems perfectly okay with this, but the resulting JS produces the obvious error:

> originalObject.prop.c is undefined

### `.tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./resources/js/*"]
    },
    "types": [
        "vite/client"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Please show us your `tsconfig`.

Comment: it looks like a problem either with ts or with how ts is configured. The right signature for run should be `<T extends Base>run(arg: { prop: T})`. at which point the assignment in `run` would not be valid.

Comment: @njzk2 I don't think so. This seems to just be how TS works.

Comment: @njzk2 That's a problem with the function definition, not the TS configuration.

Comment: The thing is that the function returns nothing. It only changed variable in place.

Comment: I'm trying to remember how this would work in Java, and I'm fairly sure that 
`type A = { prop: Base };` would not be compatible with `type B = { prop: SubTest };`

Comment: @Blaz And that's why mutable data is a bad idea - immutability all the way. I don't understand why people seem so reluctant to use the `readonly` modifier on `interface` types in TypeScript.

Comment: @njzk2 Typescript uses structural typing, which is also known as duck-typing, which only checks if the required shape is reached

Answer (score 2):

Since, `SubTest` extends `Base`, which means that `SubTest` is a sub-type of `Base`, you can pass any `SubTest` as `Base`. You can interpret that to how OOP works, you can pass a child class to a method that expects the parent class. The issue here is that for Typescript everything is fine since you expect exactly a `Base` and as mentioned before, `SubTest` obeys this condition.

The reason why such an assignment is possible is due to Typescript's type system, which is known as [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), that only checks if the needed shape of the type is reached and doesn't check for the additional fields. In simple words compared to Java, Typescript checks only for the existence of the required fields, while Java checks for the exact identity.

Basically, you could define another type that is independent of `Base`, but has its all fields, and `run` wouldn't complain about it:

```
type NotBase = {
   a: number;
   b: number;
}

const notBase: NotBase = {a: 1, b: 2};

run({ prop: notBase }); // no error
```

If we refer to [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) we can see exactly the same situation happening:

```
interface Point {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}
 
function logPoint(p: Point) {
  console.log(`${p.x}, ${p.y}`);
}

const point = { x: 12, y: 26 };
logPoint(point); // no error
```

> The `point` variable is never declared to be a `Point` type. However, TypeScript compares the shape of `point` to the shape of `Point` in the type-check. They have the same shape, so the code passes. The shape-matching only requires a subset of the object’s fields to match.

Same docs:

```
const point3 = { x: 12, y: 26, z: 89 };
logPoint(point3); // no error
 
const rect = { x: 33, y: 3, width: 30, height: 80 };
logPoint(rect); // no error
```

To make the function safer, you should add a generic argument that extends `Base`:

```
function run<T extends Base>(arg: { prop: T }) {}
```

Now, in this function if you try to do the assignment to `arg.prop`, you will get an error:

```
function run<T extends Base>(arg: { prop: T }) {
  arg.prop = { // error here
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
  };
}
```

> Type '{ a: number; b: number; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> '{ a: number; b: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Base'.

This error means that since you expect something that extends `Base` it is not safe to assume that it is exactly `Base`.

To fix this error you can do the following:

```
function run<T extends Base>(arg: { prop: T }) {
  arg.prop = {
    ...arg.prop,
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
  };
}
```

This way you add all necessary fields of `T` and change the known ones from the `Base` (`a` and `b`).

As an alternative to spread you could assign `a` and `b` separately:

```
  arg.prop.a = 1;
  arg.prop.b = 1;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwLACgpTgLigDsBXAWwCMIAnAbm1wsNMpvqwF93tRIoBlEhQAqEBMCip4SKADJ0DKAGNm5KnWxds2AGYkiS4AEsA9kSjV9AHmFQIAD2AQiAEwSxEEAHwAKONQBzQjQoMGoTMEJbDgBKBRw8QIA6MIjJeNxcJOz-AJTwsAAaRVwCKABGYoTGQgAmKtwtTm0sJTNxUILCQRExCVRMBLLKxSYoesUVKABmKqbsNqIOk2ojAKMiOAAbAHkKACsIQ3SQ1LAoeaxLIh8VtY3tvcPDGO5W9pMtiCStkwDb1brTa7A5HYD5CJJJRJYAmABiRnsEBcPlqMVe2CAA)

Alternatively, you can restrict the `run` to accept pure `Base` again by using the generics:

```
function run<T extends Base>(arg: { prop: OnlyBase<T> }) {}
```

Now, let's define `OnlyBase`:

```
type OnlyBase<T extends Base> = {} extends Omit<T, keyof Base> ? T : never;
```

This type will check if the `T` will be an empty object after removing all of the keys of `Base`. If that's true that we can assume that `T` is base, otherwise return `never` to raise an error. Though, for the compiler this conditional won't change the type inference and you will still have to spread the `arg.prop` to remove the error described previously.

Testing:

```
const prop: Base = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
};

const originalObject = { prop };

run(originalObject);

const prop2: SubTest = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
};

const originalObject2 = { prop2 };

run(originalObject2); // expected error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwLACgpTgLigDsBXAWwCMIAnAbm1wsNMpvqwF93tRIoBlEhQAqEBMCip4SKADJ0DKAGNm5KnWxdsPcNADyRADYhpEADzCoEAB7AIRACYJYiCAD5J6Dldv2nUPTIAS2ALABooAGsIEAB7ADMXJA8AfihLZggANzZtLHiSIiVgINiiKGpCix87R2dTNwAKOGoAc0I0KDBqWLBCA2NTCw8OAEovPKUy8S6evqSUBRw8QgBGMMUmKAAmDc5uLCmiGdjqINagojhDPQoAKwhiz07u3qgtLGxKokbT88vrrcHsVRgcjjNXmBtoRBCIxBJUJhlgQoOtNoRdooVFAAMx7D7YcESP4XK43e6PYDbZ6zXrUglYb6-M6kwEU4rbUFQAD03J8kGKEAcVmoPWo2CAA)

Comment: "for Typescript everything is fine" but it shouldn't be, though, that's the whole point of having types. I don't think that the types `type A = { prop: Base }` and `type B = {prop: SubTest }` ought to be compatible

Comment: @njzk2 please check this [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system). You can see in the code snippet that you are allowed to pass `rect` to `logPoint` even though `rect` has additional fields

Comment: thanks for the ref. I think it's a big flaw in the definition of the language, though, possibly even a bug? it completely breaks the trust in the type system!

Comment: @wonderflame What fascinates me about this is that TypeScript throws `'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Base'` when we're using generics, but not otherwise. (This was actually the whole motivation for the post.) Any idea why TS is so concerned about it when we're using generics and not when we pass an object of explicit type?

Comment: @JacobLockard as the statement itself says. `T extends Base`, not `T is Base`, which means that is not safe to assume that `T` is equal to `Base`. Without generics there is no point to assume that passed object can be anything else.

Comment: @wonderflame But, as my question illustrates, it's not **really** safe to assume that a parameter of any type is equal to that type, right? TS expressly allows subtypes.

Comment: @JacobLockard Unfortunately this is the problem with the whole type system that typescript was designed over. I have updated my answer to prevent passing anything other than the pure `Base`

Comment: @wonderflame Got it. Would you mind clarifying that in the answer? I'm having a hard time following the logic of this statement: `The reason why such assignment is possible is due to Typescript's type system, which is known as structural type system, that only checks if the needed shape of the type is reached and doesn't check for the additional fields.` Could you explain why exactly this produces the behavior in question?

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, I'm mostly confused because in Java I can still do: `Apple a; Fruit fruit = a;`

Comment: @JacobLockard you can do it here as well. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwLACgpTgLigDsBXAWwCMIAnAbm1wsNMpvqwF93tRIoBlEhQAqEBMCip4SKADJ0DKAGNm5KnWxds2JQHsi4vIUEixE1JhxGoARgA0iplABMDqyqgBmN1qw79hk7SKHjsQA)

Comment: @wonderflame Right, I just mean that since I can do it in both languages, it's not really an adequate explanation for the problem in TS.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript allows assignment of a subtype to an object property because it supports structural typing and allows for flexibility in object shapes. This behavior is intentional and part of TypeScript's design philosophy.

In your example, the **run** function accepts an argument of type **{ prop: Base }**, which means it expects an object with a property named prop of type Base. When you pass originalObject to the **run** function, the type checker sees that **originalObject.prop** matches the expected type Base since **SubTest** is a subtype of **Base**. This is because **SubTest** extends Base by adding an additional property c.

At compile-time, TypeScript allows this assignment because it verifies that the provided object has at least the required properties of Base. However, during runtime, when you access **originalObject.prop.c**, you will encounter an error because the actual object does not have the c property defined.

This behavior is a trade-off between static type checking and runtime behavior. TypeScript's design aims to catch potential type errors early in the development process and provide a better development experience by providing type safety and code completion. However, it cannot guarantee runtime behavior since JavaScript is a dynamically-typed language.

To avoid runtime errors, you can refine the type of **originalObject.prop** to **SubTest** when passing it to the **run** function, like this:

```
run({ prop: prop });
```

By providing the specific type, the type checker will catch any inconsistencies at compile-time, and the runtime behavior will match the expected type.

Comment: I suspected as much. Would you be interested in adding an example of a (more) strictly-typed language (like Java) for comparison? I believe that would help me understand even better.