# How to write a function that modifies a given property of an object where the property must be a certain type?

Tags: typescript

What I want to do:

```js
type Apple = {
  seeds: number,
  size: number
};

const apple = {
  seeds: 5,
  size: 2
};

double(apple, 'seeds');
double(apple, 'size');

console.log(apple); // => { seeds: 10, size: 4 }
```

This is trivial in JS:

```js
function double(object, property) {
  object[property] *= 2;
}
```

In TS it's an absolute nightmare. This obviously doesn't work:

```
function double<T>(object: T, property: keyof T) {
  object[property] *= 2;
}
```

> The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type

I had high hopes of this working, but... no luck:

```
function double<T extends { [k in K]: number }, K extends keyof T>(object: T, property: K) {
  object[property] *= 2;
}
```

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.
> 'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T[K]', but 'T[K]' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'number'.

I think it's odd that TS should enforce this when [it won't do so for non-generics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76477605/4713952), but so be it. Any better ideas?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmYBtoF4oG8CwAoKUDOEEAJngFxQB2ArgLYBGEATgNza54CWAXhOdfU1ZYAvkOwBjAPYU8wKAEN4SKKkw58hEuQCsAGjb5uvKACZ9IsVgBmVCuOAdpUIpKp0kAHgDSUCAA9gCAoSfGBGDgoAcwA+AApJOgArCHtyACUUyUYib11KWgZGaLywRklIRlByLwBKdAME5PsAbVLyplAAXSgAKlQTIWFsbBc3JFjFRAg8gHICYjwZmqFR9wgJpWmoOaMloSA) work for you? It doesn't have autosuggestions for the `property` but it works. If that works for you, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am i missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Looks perfect! I guess I was approaching it from the wrong angle. If you write an answer I'll definitely accept it.

Comment: sure, will do in a bit

Comment: @wonderflame When you do, it might be a good idea to outline the weaknesses of this approach. I can think of several cases where it wouldn't work, particularly if the `double` function needed to return something related to the original type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options here:

First. No need to define a generic for an object, only define `K` and make `object` parameter be of type `Record<K, number>`:

```
function double<K extends string>(object: Record<K, number>, property: K) {
  object[property] *= 2;
}

double(apple, 'seeds');
double(apple, 'size');
double(apple, 'invalid'); // error
```

The downside of this approach is that there are no autosuggestions for the `property`

Second. Define two generics `T` and `K extends keyof T`, however, we won't type `object` as `T` but rather just a `Record<K, number>`:

```
function double<T, K extends keyof T>(object: Record<K, number>, property: K) {
  object[property] *= 2;
}

double(apple, 'seeds'); // autosuggestions working
double(apple, 'incorrect'); // error
```

The advantage is that autosuggestions are now working. The compiler is able to infer the type for `T` the because we have typed `object` as `Record<K, number>`, and since `K` extends `keyof T`, `object` is `T`. The downside of this method is that `object` is required to have only `number` fields, otherwise the compiler will raise an error, since `K` will be a union of all keys, meaning that all fields of `T` are numbers.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#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)